# Vue date pick datetime not working on modal

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using `bootstrap-vue` and the third party plugin `vue-date-pick` for a date-time picker. I am trying to show it on a `b-modal`.

When I click on the field, it shows the date-time picker, but the problem is that after selecting a date the picker is closing without allowing me to select a time. In order to set the time I must reopen the picker.

It's working fine outside `v-model`.

Here's the `b-modal`:

```html
<b-modal
    id="comment-modal"
    ref="modal"
    title="Assignment Comment"
    no-close-on-backdrop
    centered
    @hide="closeModal"
>
    <b-form-group
        label="Due Date"
    >
    <date-pick style="padding-right: 20px !important;"
        v-model="due_date"
        :format="'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'"
        :pickTime="true"
        :autoclose="true"
        :isDateDisabled="isFutureDateTime"
        :inputAttributes="{readonly: true}"
    ></date-pick>
    </b-form-group>
    <template v-slot:modal-footer>
        <b-button size="sm" variant="secondary"  @click="closeModal()">Cancel</b-button>
        <b-button size="sm" variant="primary" @click="assignTo()">Submit</b-button>
    </template>
</b-modal>
```

Script:

```js
import DatePick from "vue-date-pick";
import "vue-date-pick/dist/vueDatePick.css";
components: {
  DatePick
},
methods{
  isFutureDateTime(date){
    const currentDate = new Date(Date.now() - 86400000);
    return date < currentDate;
  },
}
```

Outside the modal it's working fine, but within the model it's not waiting until I select a time; it closes when I click a particular date.

Comment: can u add a fiddle or codepen for it?